# C# Linq expression to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have this in C#

```
private Expression<Func<ObjectCollection, IEnumerable<string>>> _propertySelector;
```

And set as this

```
myComboBox.PropertySelector = collection => collection.Cast<Person>().Select(p => p.Name);
```

I'm using the DLL in a VB.NET project, and would like to set myComboBox.PropertySelector

The class I'm using is 'Product' which I want to use 'Product.Name' in the selector.

I thought this would work, but it's a run-time error

```
myComboBox.PropertySelector = myComboBox.Items.Cast(Of Product).Select(Function(p) p.Name)
```

Comment: The error you're getting is going to tell you exactly what you're doing wrong.  You're assigning an `IEnumerable`, not an `Expression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myComboBox.PropertySelector = Function(x) x.Cast(Of Product).Select(Function(p) p.Name)
```

Comment: I can accept the answer only if you fix the issue, it should be myComboBox.PropertySelector = Function(x) x.Cast(Of Product).Select(Function(p) p.Name)

Comment: @sami -- u got it.